# GetVirtualPath method in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Can anyone explain how the virtual path is being calculating?
According to the RouteData.Values or according to the url pattern?

I'm trying to remove some routedata values but still the virtual path is not changes.
I have a problem that the virtual path return with redundant slash at the beginning of the URL like : /he/controller/action the slash before culture is redundant...

I'm using custom routes like the following

```
    routes.Add("Default",
             new CustomRoute("{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                 new
                 {
                     controller = "Desktop",
                     action = "Index",
                     culture = "he-IL",
                     guid = "",
                     id = UrlParameter.Optional
                 }));
  routes.Add("Wizard_" + wizard,
                        new CustomRoute("{guid}/{culture}/" + wizardName + "/{action}/{id}",
                        new
                        {
                            controller = wizard,
                            action = "Index",
                            culture = "he-IL",
                            guid = "",
                            id = UrlParameter.Optional
                        }));
```

the problem is when using Url.Action(action, controller) method and the action is in the wizard controller, so the URL for the action is wizard format like {guid}/{culture}/" + wizard + "/{action}/{id}
bu the guid value is empty and the returned URL is //he-il/controller/action
instead of /he-il/controller/action

The CustomRoute class:

```
public class CustomRoute : Route
{
    private List<string> _wizards;

    public CustomRoute(string uri, object defaults)
        : base(uri, new RouteValueDictionary(defaults), new MvcRouteHandler())
    {
        _wizards = new List<string>();
        FillWizards(ref _wizards);
        DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary();
    }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        bool hasGuid = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData != null 
            && httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values != null 
            && httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("guid") 
            && !httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["guid"].ToString().Equals(Guid.Empty);

        var routeData = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);
        if (routeData == null)
            return null;

        bool isWizard = _wizards.Contains(routeData.Values["controller"].ToString());
        Debug.WriteLine("Controller: " + routeData.Values["controller"] + " action: " + routeData.Values["action"] + " Is wizard: " + isWizard + " has guid: " + hasGuid);
        if (isWizard && !hasGuid)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(routeData.Values["guid"].ToString()))
            {
                routeData.Values["guid"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
            }
        }

        return routeData;
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        VirtualPathData path;
        path = base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values);

        return path;
    }

    private void FillWizards(ref List<string> items)
    {
        var _configuration = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IConfiguration>();
        List<string> wizards = _configuration.GetParamValue<string>("SessionUniqueWizards", "").Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

        items = wizards;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your routing configuration. Are you using the `MapRoute` extension method? Are you using custom routes? Technically, `GetVirtualPath` can return anything you want with a custom route, so show your code.

Comment: ok I'm updating my question

Comment: Please post the code for your `CustomRoute` class.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your `guid` parameter is missing is because

1. There is no `guid` parameter in your call to `Url.Action(action, controller)`.
2. There is (apparently) no `guid` parameter in the current request. That is, the current route that is being hit has no `guid` route value.
3. You have specified the default value for the `guid` (`guid = ""`). Since empty string is what you specified as the default, empty string is what you are getting by default.

For the URL to build correctly, the `guid` has to come from somewhere. [MVC always passes matching route values from the current request](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1346) when building outgoing URLs, but since not all of your URLs have a `guid` you need to specify it for the pages where it does not exist in the context:

```
Url.Action("Index", "Search", new { guid = "a565f84f9152495792d433f5bd26000f")
```

This is the normal way to do it. Typically, if you are building the link for a CRUD operation you are doing so within a list of entities.

For example, for a `Product` entity, you would normally have links for `Edit Product` and `Delete Product` for each `Product` in a list that would look something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>model.ProductName</td>
    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Product", "Edit", new { guid = model.ProductId })</td>
    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Product", "Delete", new { guid = model.ProductId })</td>
</tr>
```

There would also typically be a link to add a new entity that has no identifier.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Product", "Add")
```

But it is unclear from your example how a "wizard" would be created. Creating a new identifier should normally be a function of the `Add` method, not that of a route.

But there seems to be an issue where you are randomly generating a GUID within your route, so it is unclear how you expect this value to be maintained from one request to the next.

Comment: Yes I know that, and that's actually my question, I wrote it in my question. In case using Url.Action I don't want to use the guid, so how can I make the GetVirtualPath method not create the empty guid?

Comment: Hoe can I remove the guid so the virtual path will be created without the guid?

Comment: You can't. See my update. It is unclear how your workflow is supposed to work. Who creates the "wizard"? Does it get entered as an entity in the database? Is it stored in session? What is supposed to happen in the case the GUID is not passed? The bottom line is that there needs to be a way to get access to the wizard entity outside of the scope of the route so that the URL can be generated correctly with its identifier, but you haven't provided enough details of how your application is supposed to work to provide a complete solution.